# User approval needed to reference (entity reference) their profile (profile2)

Tags: users, entities

Here is the use case:

1. User registers, and creates "Employee Profile" (using profile2)
2. Admin user creates node of type Location
3. Location node references (using entity reference) user's "Employee Profile," and then displays all the employees at a location (using the Views module, and EVA)

It is all complete, but users whose profile is being referenced needs to give permission before their profile is displayed in the Location node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve this, at a large scale, is to create a field on the user profile (example "Allow your profile to be displayed on Locations?" Yes or No).

Using views, filter profiles by field with value equal to yes.